# how can instanceof Duplex be both Writable and Readable

Tags: javascript, node.js

consider this in a nodejs environment:
So how can duplex be an **instanceof** both Writable and Readable?

**Edit1:**
And how can this be achieved in javascript? (from what I read, javascript does not allow multiple inheritance)

**Edit2:** Seems to be the case for node v7.1.0+

```
const {Readable, Writable, Duplex} = require('stream');

const r = new Readable();  
const w = new Writable();  
const d = new Duplex();

console.log(d instanceof Duplex);      // true  
console.log(d instanceof Readable);    // true  
console.log(d instanceof Writable);    // true

console.log(r instanceof Writable);    // false  
console.log(w instanceof Readable);    // false  
console.log(w instanceof Duplex);      // false  
console.log(r instanceof Duplex);      // false

console.log(d instanceof Transform);   // false  
console.log(d instanceof PassThrough); // false

console.log(w instanceof Writable);    // true  
console.log(r instanceof Readable);    // true
```

Comment: because `Duplex streams are streams that implement both the Readable and Writable interfaces.` - [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex)

Comment: I thought javascript doesnot allow multiple inheritance. Sorry, I should modify my question.

Comment: JavaScript allows the prototype chain to be more than 1 level deep. You can't inherit more than one thing per level, but you can have as many levels as you like.

Comment: @4castle Sure, but that would mean that Writable inherited from Readable or vice versa.

Comment: @DanPrince Prototypal inheritance isn't class based. The prototype chain can be manipulated all you like.

Comment: @4castle Obviously, but `instanceof` won't respect that unless both prototypes are there. You can't have both `Writable.prototype` and `Readable.prototype` in the same chain without one inheriting from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node uses the global `Symbol.hasInstance` to define a property on the Writable constructor so that Duplex stream instances will return true for both `instanceof Readable` and `instanceof Writable`. You can see the important code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/fd16eed8ea9f94cf97bdb7c4c662a18f3e70a81c/lib/_stream_writable.js#L138-L168):

```
// Test _writableState for inheritance to account for Duplex streams,
// whose prototype chain only points to Readable.
var realHasInstance;
if (typeof Symbol === 'function' && Symbol.hasInstance) {
  realHasInstance = Function.prototype[Symbol.hasInstance];
  Object.defineProperty(Writable, Symbol.hasInstance, {
    value: function(object) {
      if (realHasInstance.call(this, object))
        return true;

      return object && object._writableState instanceof WritableState;
    }
  });
} else {
  realHasInstance = function(object) {
    return object instanceof this;
  };
}

function Writable(options) {
  // Writable ctor is applied to Duplexes, too.
  // `realHasInstance` is necessary because using plain `instanceof`
  // would return false, as no `_writableState` property is attached.

  // Trying to use the custom `instanceof` for Writable here will also break the
  // Node.js LazyTransform implementation, which has a non-trivial getter for
  // `_writableState` that would lead to infinite recursion.
  if (!(realHasInstance.call(Writable, this)) &&
      !(this instanceof Stream.Duplex)) {
    return new Writable(options);
  }
```

Comment: Thnx. basically, writable has it own instanceof method and would attach itself to any who call a writable? I think i get the general concept. I might need to read the code a few more times to completely understand its implementation

Comment: @thierry essentially when you call `foo instanceof Constructor` what is happening under the hood is something like `Constructor[Symbol.hasInstance](foo)`.

Comment: that part is ok. but mostly how using realHasInstance prevent an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Duplex implements Writable and Readable, but not through multiple inheritance.

Take a look at the source in
[lib/_stream_duplex.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_duplex.js#L14-L21).

```
util.inherits(Duplex, Readable);

var keys = Object.keys(Writable.prototype);
for (var v = 0; v < keys.length; v++) {
  var method = keys[v];
  if (!Duplex.prototype[method])
    Duplex.prototype[method] = Writable.prototype[method];
}
```

It inherits from Readable, but all the methods from Writable's prototype are also copied onto Duplex's prototype.

The `instanceof` operator simply walks up the prototype chain for the left hand side operand (`d`), checking whether it contains the prototype of the right hand side operand (`Writable`).

Because the methods are copied, not inherited, it never will. Therefore `d instanceof Writable` should always be false.

Comment: but when I do a `d instanceof Writable` I get true

Comment: Are you sure? I'm trying it locally with the latest version of Node and I definitely get `false`.

Comment: yes. but i'm on 7.1.0. I ran the exact same code. but i have imports on top.  

const {Readable, Writable, Duplex} = require('stream');